# How to extract total count for values not in array type fields

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am storing complete message thread (with messages) as a single document. Array field `participants` holds participants user ids. Every message has array field  `read_by` with user ids which read that message.

**Example data:**

```
db.threads_test.insert( { "subject" : "subject 1", "participants" : ["u1", "u2"], "messages" : [
{"message_id" : "m1", "message" : "msg 1", "read_by" : ["u1"]},
{"message_id" : "m2", "message" : "msg 2", "read_by" : ["u2"]}
]});

db.threads_test.insert( { "subject" : "subject 2", "participants" : ["u1", "u2"], "messages" : [
{"message_id" : "m3", "message" : "msg 3", "read_by" : ["u1"]},
{"message_id" : "m4", "message" : "msg 4", "read_by" : ["u1"]}
]});

db.threads_test.insert( { "subject" : "subject 3", "participants" : ["u1", "u3"], "messages" : [
{"message_id" : "m5", "message" : "msg 5", "read_by" : ["u1", "u3"]}
]});
```

I need to found out how many unread threads and how many unread messages does user have.

**Logic for interpretation is this:**

- **unread thread** is one which user is in `participants` array and has at
  least one message where user is not in `read_by`
- **unread message** is one which belong to thread which has user in
  `participants` and does not have that user in `read_by`

**Expected unread counts per user:**

```
u1: threds=1, messages=1
u2: threads=2, messages=3
u3: threads=0, messages=0
```

I've been checking the aggregation framework but could not find solution.

Mongo version is 2.4.9

Comment: Why are these totals expected? I see nothing in the data that supports the logic for these totals. I think you need to explain your logic as well or otherwise edit the data.

Comment: I added description what counts are. Thnx for pointing it out.

Comment: And corrected expected results. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an easy one for the aggregation framework and mostly due to the many arrays, so there are ways you can easily get this wrong. Fortunately there is a sound logic pattern here when you look at it closely since it just comes down to a comparison point:

```js
db.threads_test.aggregate([
    // Unwind all arrays
    { "$unwind": "$messages" },
    { "$unwind": "$messages.read_by" },
    { "$unwind": "$participants" },

    // Group on distinct "message_id" comparing "particpant" and "read_by"
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "participant": "$participants",
            "message_id": "$messages.message_id"
        },
        "unread": { 
            "$min": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$ne": [ "$participants", "$messages.read_by" ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }},

    // Get a sum of unread per thread
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id._id",
            "participant": "$_id.participant",
        },
        "unread": { "$sum": "$unread" }
    }},

    // Sum per participant counting unread threads
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.participant",
        "threads": { 
            "$sum": { 
                "$cond": [
                    { "$ne": [ "$unread", 0 ] },
                    1,
                    0
                ] 
            }       
        },
        "unread": { "$sum": "$unread" }
    }}
])
```

Which gives you the result:

```js
{ "_id" : "u2", "threads" : 2, "unread" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "u3", "threads" : 0, "unread" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "u1", "threads" : 1, "unread" : 1 }
```

The first [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage there is critical. Ater [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) being processed on each array there is going to be a lot of duplication invoved. Fortunately each level of "thread" and "message" have their own distinct "id" values. Along with the distinct "participants" themselves this is a vital point.

When you look at that data in the "unwound" form, you should be able to see through all the duplication that the "key test" here is to compare "participant" and "read_by" values to see if they are the same. And just like "processing loops" ( except all the combinations are not laid out ), then you only need to return "once" for a given message where the "participant" and "ready_by" are "equal".

This explains the "grouping" combination. With a "key" comprised of "thread", "participant" and "message_id" you only need the **`$min`** numerical result from that comparison with "read_by". So if at least "one" of "read_by" was matched then the count is `1` otherwise it's `0`.

The next stages are just careful grouping for your totals. First to get the total "unread" count per thread, then to count the threads with unread messages down to the final "participant" grouping key.

So though it's not "always" the path to finding a solution, doing all `$unwind` operations at the start is a good way for you to visualize the data so you can then understand the solution.

---

### Alternate method

As you state, you have MongoDB 2.4 available for this, and depending on the size of your collection then processing with `$unwind` like this can cause a lot of overhead. Later versions have some provision for this but it could possibly be a problem.

I mentioned earlier "processing loops", which is exactly something you can do with `mapReduce` instead.

While the aggregation framework is generally preferred here, you might need to consider this if size is a restriction:

```js
db.threads_test.mapReduce(
    function () {
      var doc = this;
      doc.participants.forEach(function(participant) {
        doc.messages.forEach(function(message) {
          var obj = {
            threads: [],
            unread: 0
          };

          if ( message.read_by.indexOf(participant) == -1 ) {
            obj.threads.push(doc._id.valueOf());
            obj.unread = 1;
          }

          emit(participant,obj);
        })
      })
    },
    function (key,values) {

      var result = { "threads": [], "unread": 0 };

      values.forEach(function(value) {
        value.threads.forEach(function(thread) {
          if ( result.threads.indexOf(thread) == -1 )
            result.threads.push(thread);
        })
        result.unread += value.unread;
      });

      return result;

    },
    { 
       "finalize": function(key,value) {
           value.threads = value.threads.length;
           return value;
       },
       "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
)
```

Same thing here really. By each participant on the thread by each message, they are compared to the "read_by" list to see if they are in there. We emit the "thread id" when the message is unread and the result if "unread". This is emitted for every message on the thread in combination with participant. So a "loop of loops".

The results are "reduced" by pulling the distinct values from "threads" and totalling the unread messages by participant.

Since "threads" is a distinct list of "id" values, we just want the length of that list in the end after reduction. So that is what "finalize" does here and converts the list to a numeric value of it's length.

Same results but not as pretty as this is a restriction of mapreduce:

```js
    "results" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "u1",
                    "value" : {
                            "threads" : 1,
                            "unread" : 1
                    }
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "u2",
                    "value" : {
                            "threads" : 2,
                            "unread" : 3
                    }
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "u3",
                    "value" : {
                            "threads" : 0,
                            "unread" : 0
                    }
            }
    ],
```

No matter which one suits you best, the problem solution should now be clear for both the programitic brain and the aggregation brain

Answer (score 0):

I think you took the wrong end of the stick by doing like that (my opinion and I might be wrong).

It might be better to create multiple collections. Why not having table scalled `threads`, `messages` and `user_read`:

```
Collection threads:
{thread_id: "...", subject: "...", participants: ["u1", "u2"], ...}
{thread_id: "...", subject: "...", participants: ["u1", "u3"], ...}
...

Collection messages:
{thread_id: "...", user_id: "...", message: "..."}
{thread_id: "...", user_id: "...", message: "..."}
...


Collection user_read:
{user_id: "u1", type: "thread", id: "..."}
{user_id: "u1", type: "message", id: "..."} # Care here the type is a message
...
```

Now you know that there are X threads by counting in the first collection (let's call this `nbrThreads`). And you can count the number of threads (using `type=='thread'`) read by "u1" easily in `user_read` (let's call it `userThreadsRead`). Thus:

```
unreadThread = nbrThreads-userThreadsRead
```

Same logic for the message by counting in the second collection and (using `type=='message'`) on `user_read` table. Calling those variables nbrMessages and userMessagesRead

```
unreadMessage = nbrMessages-userMessagesRead
```

Also if you can't change the structure, I would suggest to reorganize a bit your structure to be able to do something similar. I should be possible to do the same thing with your structure by getting the length of the array.

Best regards !

Comment: I have threads and messages in the same collection to enable search by subject and message at once. Separate collection for read state? Interesting, I'll check that. Although I wanted to tied all together to be more nosql way.

Comment: Nosql doesn't mean putting everything into a single collection. The problem is that putting array in collection objects will be very time consuming if you need to operate on multiple node ;). But if you only need to grab them and display them it's perfect (which is not the case, in my mind, for your problem).

Comment: Well, in one moment I certainly have to put values in arrays (mark message as read). Multiple nodes, you mean multiple mongodb nodes (we do not have that right now)? Or marking multiple messages at once? Anyway, those threads will be mainly between 2-3 persons and I do not expect any performance and concurrency  issues. I just trying to have simple architecture.

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant putting and array into an object of a row instead of directly having the array into the row (at the first level depth).